# Hibernate no default value found having multiple manytomany mappings to the same entities

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

User has these :

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "votedDownBy")
private Set<Foo> votedDown =new HashSet<Foo>();

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "favouritedBy")
private Set<Foo> favourites = new HashSet<Foo>();
```

The corresponding Foo has these :

```
@ManyToMany
private Set<User> votedDownBy = new HashSet<User>();

@ManyToMany
private Set<User> favouritedBy = new HashSet<User>();
```

When deploying I am getting no default value provided for votedDownBy_id ... and I don't know why ?

Answer (score 0):

`@ManyToMany` mappings are done using join tables. In your case, there must be a `Foo_User` table that has these mappings. i.e, a `Foo_id` and a `User_id` column. (Substitute `Foo_id` and `User_id` with the respective primary keys. Also substitute `Foo_User` with `Table1_Table2` where `Table1` is the table for `Foo` and `Table2` for `User`)

You can override these defaults using the `@JoinTable` annotation:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "votedDownBy")
@JoinTable(name="User_Foo_Votedown", 
            joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="User_ID")}, 
            inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="Foo_id")})
private Set<Foo> votedDown =new HashSet<Foo>();

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "favouritedBy")
@JoinTable(name="User_Foo_Fav", 
            joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="User_ID")}, 
            inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="Foo_id")})
private Set<Foo> favourites = new HashSet<Foo>();
```

and

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "votedDown")
private Set<User> votedDownBy = new HashSet<User>();

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "favorites")
private Set<User> favouritedBy = new HashSet<User>();
```

You can also put the `mappedBy` annotation in `User` and the `JoinTable` in `Foo` since this is a symmetric bidirectional relationship.

Comment: ok thanks, I migth as well write the sql myself ... is there no easier way ?

Comment: Not that I know of. Of course you can write sql. But writing the sql will become more and more painful in the long run. If your application doesn't need to do too many fancy database operations or handle too much scale, then hibernate is the better way to go. It will be a lot less pain to maintain it once you get it.

Comment: you have two mappedBy annaotions (well four in total), this won't work

Answer (score 0):

Just adding join table to each mapping fixed it, foo class now looks like this :

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name="user_foo_vote_down")
private Set<User> votedDownBy = new HashSet<User>();

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name="user_foo_favourite")
private Set<User> favouritedBy = new HashSet<User>();
```